# make a seperate Apicontroller from Applicationcontroller with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise, rails-routing

I am trying to make a separate `ApplicationController` for a web app and for an api.  I am able to succesfully create a separate `Api::ApplicationController` and `ApplicationController`.  The problem is I cannot get devise routes to go through the Api::ApplicationController Here are my routes:

```
devise_for :users
namespace :api do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'ApiUser', at: :auth, controllers: {
    token_validations:  'api/token_validations',
    sessions:           'api/sessions',
    registrations:      'api/registrations',
    confirmations:      'api/confirmations'
  }
  get 'boston_api', to: 'cities#boston'
end
```

Here's the result of rake routes:

```
                new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
                    user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
            destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
                   user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
               new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
              edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                                 PATCH  /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
        cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
               user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
           new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
          edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                                 PATCH  /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                                 PUT    /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                                 DELETE /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
        new_api_api_user_session GET    /api/auth/sign_in(.:format)            api/sessions#new
            api_api_user_session POST   /api/auth/sign_in(.:format)            api/sessions#create
    destroy_api_api_user_session DELETE /api/auth/sign_out(.:format)           api/sessions#destroy
           api_api_user_password POST   /api/auth/password(.:format)           devise_token_auth/passwords#create
       new_api_api_user_password GET    /api/auth/password/new(.:format)       devise_token_auth/passwords#new
      edit_api_api_user_password GET    /api/auth/password/edit(.:format)      devise_token_auth/passwords#edit
                                 PATCH  /api/auth/password(.:format)           devise_token_auth/passwords#update
                                 PUT    /api/auth/password(.:format)           devise_token_auth/passwords#update
cancel_api_api_user_registration GET    /api/auth/cancel(.:format)             api/registrations#cancel
       api_api_user_registration POST   /api/auth(.:format)                    api/registrations#create
   new_api_api_user_registration GET    /api/auth/sign_up(.:format)            api/registrations#new
  edit_api_api_user_registration GET    /api/auth/edit(.:format)               api/registrations#edit
                                 PATCH  /api/auth(.:format)                    api/registrations#update
                                 PUT    /api/auth(.:format)                    api/registrations#update
                                 DELETE /api/auth(.:format)                    api/registrations#destroy
         api_auth_validate_token GET    /api/auth/validate_token(.:format)     api/token_validations#validate_token
                api_auth_failure GET    /api/auth/failure(.:format)            devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                                 GET    /api/auth/:provider/callback(.:format) devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_success
                                 GET    /omniauth/:provider/callback(.:format) devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#redirect_callbacks
                omniauth_failure GET    /omniauth/failure(.:format)            devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                                 GET    /api/auth/:provider(.:format)          redirect(301)
                  api_boston_api GET    /api/boston_api(.:format)              api/cities#boston
```

The routes look good to me, but for some reason the api requests are still going through the regular `ApplicationController`.  How do I fix this?

Comment: My guess is because your API controller still inherits from ApplicationController. It should inherit from Api::ApplicationController.

Comment: I have it so Api::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

Comment: That's what I mean. If you don't want API requests to go through ApplicationController, don't let Api::ApplicationController inherit from ApplicationController.

Comment: It doesn't.  It inherits from  ActionController::Base

Comment: @Philip7899 great question, have you found a solution in 3 years?